# cannot download data in csv format from yahoo with python or java

Tags: java, python

i have two p rograms (java and python) which download data from yahoo finace.
I am using this URL

http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GE&f=sl1d1

It has always worked until two days ago. i tried to debug, but it seems that yahoo has problems in sending data via csv format.
if i use the same URL used in normal yahoo html page

http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=GE&ql=1

everything works fine.

could anyone assist? i have opened the same url for the last year and it has alwasy worked...

thanks and regards
 marco

here's sample python code i am using (opening a URL)

f = urllib2.urlopen(myurl)
data = f.read()
print data

Comment: Works fine for me. Well, there's only 1 entry in the file, but it's a valid CSV. Maybe they just modified their endpoints or usage conditions?

Comment: Post details about any exception you might be getting. Maybe try a packet analyzer like Wireshark if it comes down to it.

Comment: FWIW, there doesn't seem to be a newline at the end of the single line of data returned which could be make it appear to your code it's not working. What sort of data and how much of it do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

try downloading the data from this link

http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=GE&d=5&e=12&f=2012&g=d&a=0&b=2&c=1962&ignore=.csv

Comment: It's not obvious from the question in its current form what exactly the OP expects the link to return.